# Returned by a subquery

Tags: database, postgresql

**GOAL**

I have a table A with column NAME, I would like that whenever column NAME of table A, is equal to column NAME of table B, is selected in column CODE_CLIENT of table B

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN name = (select name from tb_get_names) 
THEN (select code_client from tb_get_names) 
ELSE 'null' 
END AS Result FROM tb_get_clients
```

**OUTPUT**

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the 2 subqueries you use, return all the names or all the code_clients of the table `tb_get_names`. This is why you get the error.
You need a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
  c.name,
  n.code_client AS Result
FROM tb_get_clients AS c LEFT JOIN tb_get_names AS n
ON n.name = c.name
```

Comment: sorry, all returned null    :/

Comment: Then there are not any names matching between the 2 tables

Comment: Exists, I will add how I am running the query in the question

Comment: If tb_get_gap is tb_get_clients and tb_get_customers is tb_get_names and the 2 tables have common values in the column customer, then the only reason that you get nulls is because `cust_cmdb` is actually null in tb_get_customers. If this is not the case then you are doing something wrong. In any case post sample data and expected results in text format.

Comment: I made some changes as per your example, and it worked, thanks!